# Why does $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$ imply $\alpha$ is algebraic?

Tags: field-theory

Let $E/F$ be a field extension.

Let $\alpha\in E$ such that $F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]$.

Then, how do I prove that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]$ $\implies$ $1/\alpha\in F[\alpha]$

$$\dfrac{1}{\alpha}=c_1+c_2a+...+c_na^{n-1}$$

Hence, $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: Is it an if and only if?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is algebraic then $F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]$.

Answer (score 2):

If they are the same then $\alpha^{-1} \in F[\alpha]$ (let us ignore the corner case it is $0$).

Thus 
$$\alpha^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^n b_i \alpha^{i}$$
for some $n$ and $b_i$.

Multiplying by $\alpha$ and rewriting the expression will yield a vanishing polynomial expression in $\alpha$.

Comment: what is the meaning of writing almost same anwer ?

Comment: You wrote your answers at almost the same time.

Comment: @mesel perhaps he didn't see the initial answer posted (maybe quid was writing his own answer). Anyhow, this is somewhat clearer given that it explicitly states that $n$ and $b_i$ are arbitrary

Comment: @DanZimm,@qid: If there was no intent, it is ok for me.

Comment: @mesel I started to answer the question when there was no answer. I did see your answer appear. But, I mention that $\alpha$ must be non-zero, do not mix $\alpha$ and $a$, and give a somewhat more detailed explication.  As far as this type of standard question is concerned, I feel the answers are different. (I sometimes do discard such drafts or even delete after posting but in this case I believe that my answer actually adds a little.)

Comment: @quid: Actually no-need for saying $\alpha$ is nonzero.

Comment: @mesel so what is $1/ \alpha$ when $\alpha$ happens to be $0$?

Comment: Answers posted within 2-3 or a little more minutes more likely were done independently, just one of the writers is faster than the other one.

Comment: @quid $\alpha$ is preassumly not an element of F.

Comment: @mesel OP says it is an element of $E$ (no condition). Now obviously the problem is trivial if the element is in $F$, still it is not excluded.